# 'STRING_SIZE_TOO_LARGE' while accessing ABAP CDS via Excel Odata connection

Tags: excel, odata, abap, cds

I added a new timestamp dec-15 field to an existing cds view. When I try to access it via web browser using this new field as a filter, it fetches the data. However, it gives 'STRING_SIZE_TOO_LARGE' while loading it via excel. It shows data preview just fine.

What could be the issue?

Further, I tried this using other machines. On my own machine, it gives the error 'property does not exist' in excel, while works in the browser.

```
define view ZTV_I_AH
  as select from srmprotocol
{
  key  poid_id,
  key  timestamp,
  key  xuser                                                                                                           as ChangedBy,

       arg1                                                                                                            as ChangedFrom,
       arg2                                                                                                            as ChangedTo,

       arg_string                                                                                                      as FieldChanged_code,

       substring(display_name, 7, 10)                                                                                   as CaseId,

       tstmp_to_dats( timestamp,
                      abap_system_timezone( $session.client,'NULL' ),
                      $session.client,
                      'NULL' )                                                                                         as timestamp_date,

       concat( concat(cast( SUBSTRING( cast( timestamp as abap.char( 30 )), 7, 2) as abap.dats ), '.'),
                           concat(cast( SUBSTRING( cast( timestamp as abap.char( 30 )), 5, 2) as abap.dats ),
                           concat('.', cast( SUBSTRING( cast( timestamp as abap.char( 30 )), 1, 4) as abap.dats ))))   as ChangedDate,

       tstmp_to_tims( timestamp,
                       abap_system_timezone( $session.client,'NULL' ),
                       $session.client,
                       'NULL' )                                                                                        as ChangedTime_ts,

       substring( cast(timestamp as abap.char( 23 )), 1, 14 )                                                          as timestamp_char,

       concat( concat(cast( SUBSTRING( cast( timestamp as abap.char( 30 )), 9, 10) as abap.tims ), ':'),
                    concat(cast( SUBSTRING( cast( timestamp as abap.char( 30 )), 11, 12) as abap.tims ),
                    concat(':', cast( SUBSTRING( cast( timestamp as abap.char( 30 )), 13, 14) as abap.tims ))))        as ChangedTime_2,

       cast( substring( cast(timestamp as abap.char( 23 )), 1, 14 ) as abap.numc( 30 ) )                               as timestamp_numc,

       cast( cast( substring( cast(timestamp as abap.char( 23 )), 1, 15 ) as abap.numc( 23 ) ) as abap.dec( 15, 0 ) )  as timestamp_decm

       ////// EOM: ADDED BY RMANE 03.03.2021/////////

}
where
      sps_id = 'ZNBR_SPS_CASE'
  and act_id = 'ATTRIBUTE_CHANGE'



define view ZTV_I_AH_01   as select from ZTV_I_AH {

  key poid_id,   key timestamp,   key ChangedBy,
      ChangedFrom,
      ChangedTo,
      FieldChanged_code,
      CaseId,
      timestamp_date,
      ChangedDate,
      ChangedTime_ts,
      substring( timestamp_char, 9, 14 )       as time_char,

      concat(concat(concat(concat(substring( timestamp_char, 9, 2 ), ':' ), substring( timestamp_char, 11, 2 )), ':'),
      substring( timestamp_char, 13, 2 ))      as time_char2,

      substring( timestamp_char, 9, 2 )        as HOURS_1 }


define view ZTV_I_AH_02
  as select from ZTV_I_AH_01

{

  key poid_id,
  key timestamp,
  key ChangedBy,
      ChangedFrom,
      ChangedTo,
      FieldChanged_code,
      CaseId,
      timestamp_date,
      ChangedDate,
      ChangedTime_ts,
      DATS_TIMS_TO_TSTMP(timestamp_date, ChangedTime_ts,abap_system_timezone( $session.client,'NULL' ),
                       $session.client,
                       'NULL' ) as UTCTDATETIME,
      
      time_char,

      time_char2,

      case
      when HOURS_1 < '12' then 'AM'
      else 'PM'
      end as SCHEDULED

define view ZTV_C_AH
  as select from ZTV_I_AH_02 
      @Consumption.hidden: true
  key poid_id,
  key ChangedBy,
      CaseId,
      timestamp_date                              as ChangedDate,
      ChangedTime_ts                               as ChangedTime,
      UTCTDATETIME                                  as UTCdatetime,  //NEW    
      ChangedFrom,
      ChangedTo,
      FieldChanged_code

}
```

Comment: Search SAP Support when there is a bug with SAP framework. I can find this note: [Note 2601445 - Requesting large amount of data through the Gateway is slow and might end up with dumps: STRING_SIZE_TOO_LARGE, TSV_TNEW_PAGE_ALLOC_FAILED](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/0002601445)

Comment: Hi Sandra, thanks for the reply. I did check this. This happens even with minimum data. Much more data was being fetched earlier before this new field was added. Also, this works fine in the browser. Data is fetched without any issues. Only fails in excel. That's the reason why I posted this.

Comment: Can you provide us with [a code sample of the simplest CDS view possible which still reproduces the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? That way we can see the problem ourselves and might be more successful at finding a solution.

Comment: how do you load it via Excel?

Comment: @Philipp Unfortunately it is a nested cds view. Am not sure how to share it.

Comment: @Suncatcher using the data tab->odata

Comment: @Philipp Please chcek the update. I have added all code. 'UTCDATETIME' is the new field.

Comment: And that's the most simple CDS view you can create which still produces the error? When you remove *anything* from that, the error disappears?

Comment: @Philipp yes. If I remove that field I don't get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, EXCEL doesn't handle DEC15 very well. I converted it to NUMC and it is now working fine.